# How to find machine module name for `drush dl`?

Tags: 7, drush

Long time Drupal front-end dev but doing more site building lately and have been using Drush much more. One of the biggest limitations I've found with downloading (dl) command is that you have to know the machine name of the module, which is not a big issue for say Views or Context. But who knows the machine name of stuff like node reference or simple google maps?

I guess and get it right sometimes, or I have to hit d.o to figure it out. Is there a list function I havent uncovered? The other answers to this on Stack Overflow and Drupal Answers are pretty bad.

```
drush dl module-name-here
```

Comment: That would be 21052 modules as of now. https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module/index

Answer (score 3):

According to my experience, I know machine names of some commonly used modules,
but basically when it is for new module or when I have doubt in machine name, 
I google it the module name, it should provide you with link for drupal project page,

the url will be in the format   https://drupal.org/project/[project-machine-name]

```
drush dl [project-machine-name]
```

for multiple module you can do like this

```
drush dl [project-machine-name1] [project-machine-name2][project-machine-name2] ..
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this is basically what I do. Sure would be nice to just type drush module-list. Look at how they do it in Bower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114781/bower-registering-local-git-package

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of modules available for Drupal 7 alone, and new modules are added to drupal.org at a fairly high rate.  It would be hard to compete with Google + drupal.org searching in terms of finding modules, and you're probably going to want to visit the module's project page to figure out if it's the right one for you anyway.

Once you are on the drupal.org module page, you can look at the URL:  the machine name is the name used there (i.e. https://drupal.org/project/machinename).

Comment: Yeah but look at a tool like Bower, which is a JS package manager. I don't know any language getting more modular pieces added to it than JS - and Bower manages to keep up. Just wish we had something like this for Drupal.

Comment: There once was drush iq (https://drupal.org/project/drush_iq), but we'll need to fix the web services removed in the drupal.org d7 upgrade before we add more to support issue and project searching.

Comment: Doesn't bower also take the project machine name?

Comment: For bower you just enter a pretty simple command to tell the system you have a package to register: bower register package-name-here git://github.com/automatonic/linksoup. We could have drush register and it would follow the same CLI convention. I guess at this point, this thread has officially turned into a feature request ;)